# Dot product returns symbolically when undesired

Tags: syntax

```
StateProb[state_, projector_] := 
 Dot[state, projector, state]; StateProb[state1, 
 Projector[{-(I/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}]]
```

[image: The literal MatrixForm of state, ".", MatrixForm of projector, ".", and the MatrixForm of state.]

State is {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]},

Projector is Projector[e_] :=
MatrixForm[Outer[Times, e, e]]

Only when I shift-enter evaluate the output of Dot[...] do I get (the correct) scalar answer, -(I/2)

How do I skip the middle step of having the dot product symbolically?

Resolved: removing MatrixForm from Projector's definition fixed it

Comment: You forgot to tell us what `state1` is and also `Projector[]`.

Comment: That helped. Projector was... Projector[\[CapitalOmega]_] := 
 Outer[Times, \[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalOmega]]; Projector[{-(I/Sqrt[
   2]), 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}].

The problem was that I had MatrixForm[] in the def for Projector, which if I'm reading the lit right has a HoldAll or something? Removing the MatrixForm from that def made StateProb immediately display the scalar.

Comment: Using `MatrixForm` or `Column` or similar is a common mistake.

Comment: In particular, Point 8 of [this answer to the Pitfalls post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/29734).